# Python: shutil.rmtree directory bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, shutil

im trying to get my %LOCALAPPDATA% path to work instead of hardcoding it, but it says it doesnt exist.

this works

```
dir_path = 'C:\\Users\\Hey123\\AppData\\Local\\Somefolder'
shutil.rmtree(dir_path)
```

but i want to use %LOCALAPPDATA% in my path, this is what im trying to get to work

```
dir_path = '%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Somefolder'
shutil.rmtree(dir_path)
```

[it gives this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McdKT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%LOCALAPPDATA%` is only valid syntax for use in cmd. That doesn't magically work in python.  `'%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Somefolder'` is just `'%LOCALAPPDATA%\\Somefolder'` - nothing more nothing less.

What you want, is [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), since `LOCALAPPDATA` is an environment variable-

```py
dir_path = os.path.join(os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA'], 'Somefolder')
```

That will construct the directory path nicely for you

Comment: Slightly better would be replacing `os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA')` with `os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA']`. The former will return `None` if it's not defined, leading to a confusing error from `os.path.join` that doesn't directly implicate the missing environment variable. The latter will directly and immediately raise a `KeyError` which more clearly tells you what is wrong.